# Painful? Moment Generating Function

Tags: calculus, statistics, normal-distribution, moment-generating-functions

Part 1

Let $X$ be a random variable with the p.d.f. $f(x)=\frac{1}{4\pi}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4}}$, compute the MGF of $X$.

So I know I want $\psi_X(t)=E(e^{tx})=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{tx}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4}}\,dx$, but I'm having a problem trying to figure out how to integrate this one, which is what I would really like a little help with.  Maybe a substitution recommendation?
I tried to change $e^{tx}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4}}$ to something like $e^{x(t-\frac{x}{4})}$, but that didn't seem to get me anywhere.

Part 2
Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are indep N(0,1) and let $Y=X_1+X_2$. Compute the MGF of Y and compare to the MGF of X. What is the  p.d.f. of $Y$?

So this part I got okay, with $\psi_Y(t)= \psi_X(t)^2= e^{t^2}$, since the MGF of $X$ is $e^t$.

So how can I finish the first integral to compare them?

Comment: On part 1: $tx-\frac{1}{4}x^{2}=t^{2}-\frac{1}{4}\left(x-2t\right)^{2}$ so try
out substitutions like $u=x-2t$

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, thank you very much!

Comment: I had a look at function $f$. In fact it cannot be a pdf. If $\phi$ denotes the pdf belonging to the standard normal distribution
then $f\left(x\right)=\frac{\phi\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}$
leading to $\int f\left(x\right)dx=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\ne 1$.

Comment: That's interesting.  I don't 100% understand your use of the phi function, but this is for my first graduate stat theory class and I do see what you mean about it not being equal to 1. I would suspect, knowing my prof, that its a slimmed down version of something else with the point of the exercise being finding the mgf's and showing the proportionality. He often goes beyond the scope of the course material and offers proofs that will be much more relevant in subsequent courses.

Comment: If you are certain that some function - let's call it $p$ - is indeed
a pdf, and another function $g$ is defined as $g\left(x\right)=ap\left(bx\right)$
where the $a$ and $b$ are constants, then it becomes easy to check
wether $g$ is a pdf as well. This because you find $\int g\left(x\right)dx=a\int p\left(bx\right)dx=\frac{a}{b}\int p\left(u\right)du=\frac{a}{b}$.
For $g$ being a pdf you need $a=b$. That's is how I used the phi
function wich is off course a pdf.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\begin{eqnarray}
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(tx - \frac{x^2}{a}\right) \,dx
  &=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(\frac{atx - x^2}{a}\right) \,dx
  = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(\frac{-(x - \frac{1}{2}at)^2 + \frac{1}{4}a^2 t^2}{a}\right) \,dx \\
  &=& exp\left(\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(\frac{-(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \,dx
  \text{ where }
  \begin{matrix}
    \mu = \frac{1}{2}at \\
    \sigma = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}a}
  \end{matrix}
\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 1):

So by drhab's comment, I obtained:
$\psi_X(t)=E(e^{tx})=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{tx}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4}}\,dx=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{tx-\frac{x^2}{4}}\,dx=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{t^2-\frac{(x-2t)^2}{4}}\,dx=\frac{1}{4\pi}e^{t^2}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-\frac{(x-2t)^2}{4}}\,dx=\frac{2\sqrt{\pi}}{4 \pi}e^{t^2}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}e^{t^2}$.
Then $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\psi_Y(t)=\psi_X(t)$, i.e.$\psi_Y(t)=2\sqrt{\pi}\cdot\psi_X(t)$ and so the p.d.f.of $Y$ is $f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4}}$.
Is this the correct way since $E(aX)=aE(X)$?